# Is it possible to set the context after the component mounts in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I wish to add the checks done (once the component mounts in CDM) to detect userAgent - for the purposes of mobile/flash/touchDevice detections to context rather than to the state. Is this possible? if so how would you do that? I am currently getting `undefined` when I attempt to access the value fo the context for the `isFlashInstalled`. Here is glimpse into the component setting the context:

`App.js`

```js
export class App extends Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    isFlashInstalled: React.PropTypes.bool
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isFlashInstalled: false
    };
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      isFlashInstalled: this.state.isFlashInstalled
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const flashVersion = require('../../../client/utils/detectFlash')();
    // I know this could be done cleaner, focusing on how for now.
    if (flashVersion && flashVersion.major !== 0) {
      this.setFlashInstalled(true);
    } else {
      this.setFlashInstalled(false);
    }
  }

  setFlashInstalled(status) {
    this.setState({isFlashInstalled: status});
  }
}
```

Later when trying to access isFlashInstalled from context I will get `undefined`

`ChildComponent.js`

```js
export class ChildComponent extends Component {
  // all the good stuff before render
  render() {
    const {isFlashInstalled} = this.context
    console.log(isFlashInstalled); // undefined
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you correctly set up context types for parent and child? I did a test and it works, see the componentDidMount that set the state asynchronously:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    color: 'red'
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      color: this.state.color
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({color: 'blue'}), 2000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>Test <Button>Click</Button></div>
    );
  }
}

Parent.childContextTypes = {
  color: React.PropTypes.string
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button style={{background: this.context.color}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

Button.contextTypes = {
  color: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

http://jsbin.com/cogikibifu/1/edit?js,output

Comment: I am still unable to make it work for me but since your answer is clearly right I am going to mark it as the answer thanks

Comment: Thank you, hope you will success